# How can I install a specific version of OpenJDK? (1.8.0_131)

Tags: apt, package-management, java, openjdk

All of the installation instructions reference using apt-get to install the default-jre package, which is fine, but as of this writing that installs OpenJDK Java 1.8.0_171.  One of our applications has trouble with this version and the vendor is telling us that the last version they certify is 1.8.0_131.  We have other servers in production with that version, but we can't seem to find a download or way to specify the _131 version when installing on a new server.  Is there a repository of older versions of packages we can pull from and install manually?  Any way to "copy" an installed package from one machine to another?

Comment: Have you tried something like: https://askubuntu.com/a/586101/681688 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [mirror](https://mirror.combahton.net/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/) hosting debian packages for OpenJDK (1.8.0_131).

You can download following debian packages for your required version 1.8.0_131.

```
openjdk-8-dbg_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb 
openjdk-8-demo_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jdk_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jre-jamvm_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jre_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-source_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_all.
```

Above packages are for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. You can copy to any other system and install manually using `sudo dpkg -i` command.

You can also download following tar file for manually installing openjdk using same link.

```
openjdk-8_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3.debian.tar.xz          
openjdk-8_8u131-b11.orig.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for the second half of my question about copying a package from one install to another, I was able to use the `dpkg-repack` package to generate a .deb file of the OpenJDK packages needed to install it 'offline' on another server as follows:

```
apt-get install dpkg-repack
dpkg-repack openjdk-8-jre-headless
dpkg-repack openjdk-8-jre
dpkg-repack ca-certificates-java
dpkg-repack java-common
```

On the target server I removed the `default-jre` package, `java-common`, and `ca-certificates-java` packages using `apt-get remove` to clear out the more recent version.

The older version could then be installed using (adjust filenames as needed):

```
dpkg -i openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb ca-certificates-java_20160321_all.deb
```

The headless package and certificates had to be installed together (dependency issue separately).  Then the others can be added (not sure if they're needed, but it worked for me):

```
dpkg -i openjdk-8-jre_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb
dpkg -i java-common_0.56ubuntu2_all.deb
```

After running all this, `java -version` gives me the expected output for the desired version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

NOTE: This covers copying a package from a server where you already have the desired version available.  If anyone can answer the first question, e.g. if there's an online repository or other way to download and install a specific OpenJDK build, please add that as an answer as well as that would be a more desirable way to approach this for future installations.